# Creating custom image in Windows store app with c#

Tags: c#, image, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Sorry in advance for the absolutely beginner question, but I'm new in WS apps.

I want to create custom image in a XAML page, in which I decide color for every pixel (I want to reproduce a fractal).

Which class should I use and how can I link it to XAML in order to see the image into the page?

Comment: One thing you could do is use a `Grid` with as many rows and columns as you have pixels. In each one, you can create a Canvas that reacts to being clicked.

Another would be to use an ItemsControl with something like a WrapGrid as the ItemsPanel. Then you can just set a max number of columns for your width.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `WriteableBitmap`. You can check [this](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Imaging/WriteableBitmapLightenExtension.cs) and [that](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Imaging/IBufferExtensions.cs) as a sample.
Basically you create a new WB, get access to the pixels stream using the `AsStream()` extension method on the `WriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer` property, then operate on the pixels in the stream. When done you `Invalidate()` the `WriteableBitmap` and the `Image` control you use to display it gets updated.